# Delete specific line(pattern) from .gz file using python for large file size

Tags: python, gzip

I am working with .gz extension file where I am required to delete specific pattern from the file with least processing time and not altering the file at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [gzip.GzipFile](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile)?  Arguments are similar to `open`.

Example of reading a lines from a file and writing to another files if a certain condition does not match:

```
import gzip

with gzip.GzipFile('output.gz', 'w') as fout:
    with gzip.GzipFile('input.gz','r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            if not your_remove_condition(line):
                fout.write(line)
```

Note that the input and output file must be different.

Comment: Thanks for the change it is working according to functionality, but I wanted to modify the same file. Here it is creating a new file name - "output.gz" and writing the original file into it. 

Can it be possible to have modification  on the same file and not create a new file

Comment: Not without reading the entire file into memory first, which is exactly what you want to avoid with the specified large files

Comment: @Lord_DeathMatch - Can you please suggest the way in which it can be done.

Comment: @shashank-anand The above answer should solve your problem efficiently memory-wise. If you require it to output to the same file, I would suggest creating a temporary file using `tempfile.mkstemp`, writing to that initially, then using `os.rename` to move it back to the original location

Comment: `shutil.move` rather; `os.rename` only works if the file doesn't already exist